# Return an actual java class

Tags: java

Imagine a scenario where I have a relationship such as "dogs live on land, fish live in water, and frogs live in both water and land." Thus, the relationship is animals and their associated living environment. So, I have my own dog class, fish class, and whatever other  animal. I also have my own land class, water class, and both class, all of which extend abstract class Environment.

Let's say I want to associate each environment type with a description, so I make a HashMap.

But, when I perform the code, I want the HashMap to be HashMap<"Some subclass of Environment", String>.

Now, let's say we have an object a that is a type dog, frog, or whatever kind of animal. I want to be able to say: `HashMap<Environment, String> = new HashMap<a.getAssociatedEnvironment(), String>;`

How do I write this getAssociatedEnvironment() method? Can I literally do something like:

```
public Class<T> getAssociatedEnvironment(Animal a) {
    if(a instanceof Dog) 
        return Dog.class
    if(a instanceof Frog) 
        return Frog.class
    . . . 
}
```

Comment: You are returning an Animal class for a method named getAssociatedEnvironment?

Comment: It sounds to me like land and water should be instances of Environment, and animal classes should be associated with a list of environments. Making Land, Water, and Both classes seems wrong; it doesn't make much sense to create an instance of Both, for example.

Comment: @user2357112 has got it -- Your question sounds like it may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code" when the real solution is to use a different approach entirely, the approach recommended by the user comment above.

Comment: The real question is how can I return a class from a method so that it can be used in a manner like: HashMap<obj.getClassOfObjectAssociatedWithThis, blah>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a type argument dynamically.
At runtime you don't even have any actual type information for generic types.
It is a pure compile-time type check to be backwards compatible.

And you might want to use

```
HashMap<? extends Environment, String> h = new HashMap<>;
```

or

```
HashMap<? super Environment, String> h = new HashMap<>;
```

depending on whether you want to add stuff to the map or not. Read more about generics if you need deeper understandment on this. :-)

---

Besides that, you might want to make `Land` and `Water` instead interfaces `LandAnimal` and `WaterAnimal` and then make `Dog` implement `LandAnimal`, `Fish` implement `WaterAnimal` and `Frog` implement both.